# Equality ker$(X{X^T})$=ker($X^T$)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

I'm trying to prove this equality:

ker$(X{X^T})$=ker$(X^T)$

One direction is obvious, but I can't figure out why if v is in ker$(X{X^T})$ then it is in ker$(X^T)$...
Any help?
Thank you

Comment: $X  X^T v= 0 \implies v^T X X^T v = 0 \implies \| X^T v \|^2 = 0 \implies X^T v = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v\in\ker(XX^T)$, then $(X.X^T).v=0$ and therefore $v^T.(XX^T).v=0$. But$$v^T.(XX^T).v=(X^T.v)^T(X^T.v)=\bigl\lVert X^T.v\bigr\rVert^2$$and therefore $X^T.v=0$. In other words, $v\in\ker X^T$.

Answer (score 1):

The other direction folows from $\langle XX^{T}v , v \rangle=\langle X^{T}v , X^{T}v \rangle =\|X^{T}v\|^{2}$ so  $XX^{T}v =0$ implies $X^{T}v=0$.